# Can you broadcast to a Shoutcast server from Android?

Tags: shoutcast

I run a shoutcast station for a small group of people. I would like the ability to broadcast to my server from my phone so that I could do live broadcasts away from home.

So far I have not found any software to do this, because searching only yields ten zillion results for streaming radio apps for listening, not broadcasting. Someone I asked tried to suggest that it was not possible to stream efficiently over a 3G connection, but frankly this is rubbish because I have streamed to my server from my laptop via a 3G stick before, and on my phone I have streamed audio and video to services like UStream etc.

Does anyone know of any software for android capable of broadcasting to a shoutcast server ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In 2023, I am using the app [OnAir - Live](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.suganthan.onair.broadcastmyself).

Not sure if it's from the same publisher as the previous one, but works fine. I have also used MediaCast for a while, but it has several problems that have been a bit painful.

The main benefits I see on OnAir:

- I can lock my screen, change apps, and the stream doesn't stop
- Supports Shoutcast V1, V2 and Icecast
- Simple setup
- Can record stream locally